# Java JAR Library compression

Tags: java, jar, compression

Is there any way to compress Java jar library after compilation? Something like ProGuard but for libraries. For example, there is library Jython 2.7.0 and I want to compress it. How can I achieve that?

EDIT: Or maybe there is a way to import Jython jar library to application after user install it on his own computer?

Comment: Please describe one clear goal or ultimate purpose in your question.  Having two semi-unrelated questions like this makes it confusing on what you are trying to accomplish.

Comment: My goal is to change size of my Jython library to minimum by compressing or any other way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you referring to is not to "compress" but to strip out unused code parts. This also works partially with libraries.

However Jython is a special case as it compiles Python code to Java. Hence without knowing the Python code you don't know what code parts of Jython are necessary. Hence you can't simply strip out much code. Furthermore the large part of Jython is not code but additional resources such as language data. 
I assume you can remove from the `org/python/icu` and it's subdirectories.

Additionally you can slim down Jython a bit by removing some of the platforms in the `jni` subdirectory. Jython comes with pre-compiled native code for different platforms:

- ARM Linux (e.g. Android)
- Darwin
- i386 Linux
- i386 SunOS
- i386 Windows
- sparcv9-SunOS
- x86_64-FreeBSD
- x86_64-Linux
- x86_64-SunOS
- x86_64-Windows

Deleting the platforms you don't support can save you about 1 megabyte.